# Voltmeter with USB/RS232

Tags: usb, test-equipment

I hope this is the right SE, otherwise I might post it on electrical.

I am searching for a voltmeter with a digital output, either RS232 or USB. The ones I came around are very costly for my purpose.

This is what I do now: To measure the voltage of a lead acid battery I use a Raspberry Pi with a MCP3208 ADC and some resistors. It works, but it is a bit of an overkill for such a simple task in my opinion.

The search term "usb voltmeter" leads mostly to USB adapters which show the voltage/current of an attached USB device. Which is not what I want or need.

I don't want to pay more than 50 €, as you can get the RPi for less.

Although not critical, a small device would be preferred.

Comment: Voltmeter.........thats just another word for Multimeter right???   Off to look for one.  Was just looking at crimping tools lol.

Comment: a voltmeter only measures voltage, a multimeter usually can do some more, like current measuring, resistance ...

Comment: There are a LOT of results for Voltmeter and USB.....but they are for measuring voltage coming from a USB port.........I am willing to bet you could build your own voltmeter for less than buying one lol, which is quite sad when you think about it.

Comment: I know about the "voltmeter usb" search term and the devices that show up using it. it's not what I search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below you will find a link to a device that has only 1 review but it is a good review.  I made the assumption that you are in or near the UK since you requested the price in Euros.  It does require software to be installed on the computer though.

[True RMS Multimeter @ Amazon UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Multimeter-Interface-Software-Supplied-Multitester/dp/B00R33U78C/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1483502618&sr=8-6&keywords=multimeter+with+usb+output) £44.99

[Lower price True RMS Multimeter @ Ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/MERCURY-TRUE-RMS-DIGITAL-MULTITESTER-WITH-USB-INTERFACE-/252144038537?hash=item3ab4f4b289:g:zXkAAOSwA4dWL1eO) £39.99 Including Shipping

Bonus:  This is a True RMS meter too.

I did find a more in depth review on this specific meter [Here](http://www.stevenhoneyman.co.uk/2016/06/mercury-mttr01-digital-multimeter-600104.html).

[Universal power supply @ Amazon UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/CostMad-Universal-Universelle-Voltage-Replacement/dp/B003Z6ZUJ2/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1483551923&sr=8-6&keywords=dc+adapter) for constant power. £8.79

[Lower price 9V Power Supply @ Ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/EU-Plug-AC-100-240V-to-DC-9V-1A-Switching-Power-Supply-Converter-Adapter-Black-T-/221793302464?hash=item33a3e937c0:g:zd4AAOSwNSxVcZhf) £1.53 Including Shipping

[Google currency conversion BP to Euro](https://www.google.com/search?q=%C2%A341.94+to+euro&oq=%C2%A341.94+to+euro&aqs=chrome..69i57.8542j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%C2%A341.52+to+euro) 48.83€ As of 01/04/2017 if you use the lesser priced options and give up the Amazon luxuries.

Comment: thanks. this seems good, however I have some concerns regarding the battery. How long does it last? currently my setup is measuring the voltage 24/7. I don't want to replace the battery every two weeks.

Comment: I hate to say this but I could not find any docs on battery life any any multi-meters.  I do know this one uses a 9V battery.  I think you might need a multi-meter to determine the load that it draws.  I know Amazons policy in the USA is almost no questions asked returns.

Comment: you could........rig a powersupply to deliver the required current/voltage to the multimeter through the battery terminals..........But as far as I can tell, the units that plug into the wall are much more expensive.

Comment: Agreed.  Also if  you are concerned about battery cost you could always go with rechargeable.  The battery replacement should only take a matter of a minute.

Comment: Problem is that I am not always around for changing the battery. With a 12V to 9V converter I am probably over my pricerange.

Comment: I have updated the answer with options for lower priced vendors that meet your price criteria, making the assumption you are in the UK but my guess is you can find other vendors if you are in a different country with similar prices.

Comment: Thanks. I might opt for your solution, altough the power supply should also come from the battery it is measuring. I know this is not optimal, but in case of a power outage the multimeter does not work anymore.

I found this device, altough it is somewhat over my intended budget: http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-electrical-sensors/yocto-volt